# Adding specific methods to class after determine device version - python

Tags: python, class, interface, decorator

I designed my framework so it will contain devices in it (classes with metadata) and a list of interfaces (objects) in it which are responsible to connect to the specific interface on the device (using the device metadata) and execute command on it and return the output.
This interfaces usually contatins methods that is handling the output that coming from the device.
**For example**: executing some show command creating dataframe with the output and returning this dataframe.

Now I've encountered that this output can be different regarding to the version installed on the device.
So I want to create modules that will contain this specific methods (that aren't generic) and add them dynamically regarding the device version (Monkey patching).
**For example**: if the device version is `1.8.20-6` I will search for `1.8.20.py` module and add it.

Now I found how to decorate those functions `@some_decorater` so they will be added to the interface class on run time.
In case I'm adding those modules by full path with the following code:

```
import importlib.util
spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location("module.name", "/path/to/file.py")
foo = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
spec.loader.exec_module(foo)
```

Does the python interpreter will automatically search for all decorated functions and will add them to interface class?
Or is there another way to deal with this problem? maybe some python package that deals with it.

Another question I have is why **pycharm** IDE isn't recognizing me modules with name x.y.z.py or x_y_z.py when I trying to import them (`import framework.Versions.x_y_z`)?

By the way , I know this is not a typical code problem question but more "how to" question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably a better idea to build a specific interface for each device, and use a factory to choose & return the proper object:

calling `get_device_adapter` with the device as argument, will return the proper `DeviceAdapter` object.

**pseudocode:**

```
class AbstractDeviceAdapter(ABC):
    def __init__(self, ...):
        initiatlize the common attributes
        ...
    def common_method_1(self):
        pass
    def common_method_2(self):
        do 2
    @abstractmethod
    def device_specific_method_0(self):
        pass
    @abstractmethod
    def device_specific_method_1(self):
        pass


class Device01Adapter(AbstractAdapterInterface):
    def device_specific_method_0(self):
        do specific stuff for device 01
    def device_specific_method_1(self):
        do specific stuff for device 01


class Device02Adapter(AbstractAdapterInterface):
    def device_specific_method_0(self):
        do specific stuff for device 02
    def device_specific_method_1(self):
        do specific stuff for device 02


def get_device_adapter(device, ...):
    """
    returns the Adapter appropriate for the given device
    """
    if '01' in device.__version__:
        return Device01Adapter(...)
    if '02' in device.__version__:
        return Device02Adapter(...)
```